# Local linearity and the differential

Tags: differential-geometry

How does the total differential relate to the tangent plane approximation? I know The total differential is the sum of the partial differentials. Not quite sure how that has a connection with the tangent plane approximation.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent plane is in fact just the shifted image of the total differential (most people just call it the differential).

Indeed, let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\Bbb R^n$, and let $f\in C^1(\Omega)$ define a surface $\Sigma$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ by the graph construction $$\Sigma=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^{n+1}:f(x)=y, x\in\Omega\}.$$
Given $z_0=(x_0,y_0)\in\Sigma$, we define the tangent plane at $z_0$ by
$$P_{z_0}\Sigma=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^{n+1}: y=y_0+\mathrm df(x_0)(x-x_0)\},$$
where $\mathrm df(x_0)\in\mathrm{Hom}\,(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R)$ is the differential of $f$ at $x_0$.